# Set data title generic ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, generics

```
  $( document ).ready(function(){

    $('.status-red').click(function(){
        var colonne_id = $('.status-red').attr('data-sort');
        data = {sort: colonne_id , '+name': $('.search-query').val()};
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            url: $('.url_sortindex').val(),
            data: data,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#body_sortindex').html(data.content);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Hi,
I have a search with this input.

```
<input type="text" value="test" placeholder="name" class="input-medium search-query form-control" name="+name" style="margin-right:5px">
```

But you see the name of this input name="+name".
My problem is, If I create a new input named "age" for example my request ajax don't work because the name is "+name". My question is, how do you set the name for example like that

```
data = {sort: colonne_id , $('.search-query').attr('name'): $('.search-query').val()};
```

I need to get the name of my input like that `$('.search-query').attr('name')`

And set my title here `data = {sort: colonne_id , '+name': $('.search-query').val()};`

I want to set `+name` in `data` to`$('.search-query').attr('name')`
I don't want the name in data is + name but a variable

I want to make my input generic.

Thanks you ;)

Comment: Because i have a home framework and the +name it's an argument for search by name here and the + it's a "like" in sql. it's possible to have +age or +country..

Comment: Ok but what doesn't work in your code?

Comment: I have edit my question, I hope I'm better clear ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
var data = {};

data['sort'] = colonne_id;
data[$('.search-query').attr('name')] = $('.search-query').val();
```

This should work. Hope it helps.

Comment: I wonder why this would not work. Did you try to log `data` and see how it looks?

Comment: The last line on you're proposition return a error who say : SyntaxError: missing formal parameter